# SharePoint Content Database on a non-SharePoint configured Database

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, sql-server, database, content

Is it advisable to have a SharePoint Content Database on a SQL Database Server that is not specific for SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

We can't speak to your particular scenario, but in general, SharePoint should have a dedicated SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

**Use a dedicated server for SQL Server**
To ensure optimal performance for farm operations, we recommend that you install SQL Server on a dedicated server that does not run other farm roles and does not host databases for other applications. this is for production.

For Dev/ testing you can use the shared sql server. read more here:

[Use a dedicated server for SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/best-practices-for-sql-server-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm#use-a-dedicated-server-for-sql-server)